# Python argparse -h option embellishment

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to add to the automatic output generated by `argparse` for the `-h` (help) option?

I'm happy with what it does automagically, but would also like to append a paragraph or two giving a short summary and some examples, a bit like a typical man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `description` parameter of the `ArgumentParser` object can be used to place text between usage and argument help. The `epilog` parameter adds text after the argument help.

Use `RawDescriptionHelpFormatter` to get multiline strings.

```py
import argparse

description = """Some description.
Another line.
"""

epilog = """Some epilog.
Another line.
"""

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description, epilog=epilog, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--someArgument', help='Argument description.')
args = parser.parse_args()
```